# Extracting Sharepoint site information from Sharepoint database

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How is the sharepoint data stored in the database? We had a sharepoint site which is not there anymore however the databases are still present. The names of the databases are:-

```
Sharepoint_AdminContent
Sharepoint_Config
WSS_Content
WSS_Search
```

Is it possible that I extract data from these database? Lets suppose I want data from an specific page of the site, which table should I look at for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint_AdminContent: Central Administration content database. It stores all configuration data for the Central Administration site collection.

Sharepoint_Config: configuration database. The configuration database contains data about the following:

- SharePoint databases
- Internet Information Services (IIS) web sites
- Web applications
- Trusted solutions
- Web Part packages
- Site templates
- Web applications
- Distributed Cache configuration objects

WSS_Content: Content Database. Content databases store all content for a site collection. This includes site documents or files in document libraries, list data, Web Part properties, audit logs, and sandboxed solutions, in addition to user names and rights.

WSS_Search: Search service database. This database is used for the search services. It contains the information that is required for searching content.

The data from an specific page of the site should be stored in the content database WSS_Content.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/database-types-and-descriptions

Comment: Great, do you know which columns of the WSS_Content should I look at to figure out what was there on which page?

Comment: Also can I somehow get to the directory where sharepoint files and documents are stored with just database?